# Elasticsearch stopped working once i installed mojave

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew

I foolishly upgraded my mac to mojave and once I did my elasticsearch (that I installed through Homebrew) stopped working.  Since then I have reinstalled it several times and I continue to receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapException: 
java.nio.file.FileSystemLoopException: 
/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.FileSystemLoopException: 
/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch
```

When I try and start it using brew services I get:

```
/Users/***/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist: 
service already loaded
Error: Failure while executing; '/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 
/Users/****/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist' 
exited with 133.
```

The only way I can get elasticsearch to start currently is running it through docker
Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: docker is the better option